# Как реализовать авторизацию(Вход в систему) через textbox в WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, password

Я хочу чтобы, когда мы вводили пароль(правильный) мы топали дальше, а если не правильный то Label становился видимым. Там было бы написано:"Пароль неверный".
На WindowsForms все легче было.Я вводил пароль через код, а за тем сравнивал его с с написанным...

Как это сделать на WPF?

На WindowsForms я это делал так:

string a = "123";
if(textBox1.Text == a) {

}

Comment: Так же не пробовали?

Comment: Не получается! VS меня ругает за то что я пишу textbox1 или TextBox...Ничего не могу с этим сделать

Comment: Ну так задайте контролу имя в разметке, типа `Name="TextBox1"` и потом по этому имени обращайтесь к нему

Comment: То есть просто написать просто   public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
         Name = "Textbox1"   
        }

Comment: Просто так написать?

Comment: Получилось!Спасибо!

Comment: Нет, задать имя надо *в разметке XAML*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вас не волнует, что пароль в открытом виде будет храниться внутри приложения и любой мало-мальский знакомый с тем, как устроены запускаемые файлы человек сразу же его отыщет, можете сделать так:

```
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox1" />
```

И в коде страницы проверяйте, как раньше. Там, где про  InitializeComponent написано.